# Bootstrap Modal with form issue

Tags: react-bootstrap4-modal

I have a modal which contains a rather long form field. All regular code according to react-Bootstrap.

When I Enter text (start typing) in a text field, the Modal body is jumping. As if the Modal is trying to force the text field into view?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: which bootstrap version do you have?

Comment: Bootstrap version 4

Comment: I had a similar problem and i solved it changing bootstrap to version `4.0.0-beta` with `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta`. Maybe it helps you too.

Comment: So do I need to remove my version of Bootstrap first? How do I do this? Uninstall it I mean.

Comment: I’ll try it. But it seems Bootstrap 3 also had this issue of “force focusing” text fields onChange events.

Comment: No, just run the command `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` to get that specific version. Check before that in your `package.json` which version you have now in case you want to return to that version.

Comment: Nope didn’t work :(

Comment: The issue can be seen accessing this page from a mobile device. https://codepen.io/AlecSPb/pen/qOobzK

Comment: Entering text causes screen to scroll to bottom.

Comment: It works fine for me :S

Comment: Check my post below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my design so I no longer use Modal. Been trying to fix this for ages. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. When I type in the first text field (mobile vertical) it looks like this???

[image: it looks like this when i type the first letter???]

Comment: It moves the page up?